# How to make loading of several files on Yii2 using kartik-v / yii2-widget-fileinput?

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I decided to upload several image files using FileInput Widget

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(),[
        'name' => 'imageFiles[]',
        'attribute' => 'imageFiles[]',
        'options' => ['multiple' => true],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'previewFileType' => 'any',
            'showPreview' => true,
            'showCaption' => true,
            'showRemove' => true,
            'showUpload' => false,
            'uploadClass' => 'hide',
            'overwriteInitial'=>false,
            'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
            'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/site/image-manager-upload']),
            'fileActionSettings' =>['showUpload' => false],
            'maxFileCount' => 10
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

**Controller/action**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Hotel();
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
        var_dump($model->imageFiles);die();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Hotel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const STATUS_OFF = 0;
    const STATUS_ON = 1;

    const TYPE_POINTS = 0;
    const TYPE_STARS = 1;

    public $imageFiles;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'hotel';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'url', 'reting_id', 'reting_type'], 'required'],
            [['text'], 'string'],
            [['reting_id', 'reting_type', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'url'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        ];
    }
```

**This is printed**

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#168 (5) { 
        ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_2793.jpg" 
        ["tempName"]=> string(36) "C:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\phpC2A1.tmp" 
        ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["size"]=> int(264672) ["error"]=> int(0) 
    }
```

**Result**

It turns out that there is only the last file in the array. If I do not use this widget, then everything is normal loaded array.

How can I do so to load and process an array of photos?

Comment: well for me your code ran fine can you show you model code , the only difference is that i am using `yii\base\Model` to upload the form and you must be using `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` for your model

Comment: can you try to remove the extra attributes you have defined in your widget declaration although it didnt made any difference on my side but just for reference, remove `'name' => 'imageFiles[]',` and `'attribute' => 'imageFiles[]',`  from your field declaration you donot need them  when you are using `ActiveForm` and remove the `'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/site/image-manager-upload']),` too as you are submitting your form to upload the files, and then try to paste the `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_FILES)` in the original post. and add `enctype=>'mutipart/form-data'` to your form and submit.

Comment: I have done. I have got it

Answer (score 0):

I have done.

```
<? echo FileInput::widget([
'name' => $model->formName() . '[imageFiles][]',
'options' => ['multiple' => true],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'previewFileType' => 'any',
    'showPreview' => true,
    'showCaption' => true,
    'showRemove' => true,
    'showUpload' => false,
    'uploadClass' => 'hide',
    'overwriteInitial'=>false,
    'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
    'fileActionSettings' =>['showUpload' => false],
    'maxFileCount' => 10
],
```

]); ?>

This is workly